# Read specific columns of data using pushback c++

Tags: c++

I have an input file which has varies columns of data, which have different data types.

I require the first two columns to be read, which are both floats, where column 1 is latitude and column 2 is longitude. I'd like to read the data and store it within a vector which can carry both the latitude and longitude.

I have used `struct` to create variables for the lat long positions, and I am trying to read them together as one `point`. Could anyone explain a more C++-ish way of doing this, or how to make my approach work? Alternatively, I could push back the two columns of data directly, using `getline`, but the understanding of this method also evades me.

The plan is to be able to access these lat long `points` so that I could make distance calculations for specific points.

My input file is equivalent to

```
#Latitude   Longitude   Depth [m]   Bathy depth [m] CaCO3 [%]
-78 -177    0   693 1
-78 -173    0   573 2
-78 -168    0   592 -999
-78 -162    0   668 2
-77 -178    0   640 2
-77 -174    0   573 1
```

My attempt is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

struct Point
        {
                double latitude, longitude;
        };

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
        ifstream inputFile("Data.txt");

        std::vector<Point> database;
        Point p;

        float latit, longit;
        if (inputFile.is_open())
        {
                while(inputFile >> latit >> longit)
                {
                //        database.push_back(Point{latit, longit});
                        database.push_back(p);

                        cout<<p.longitude << " " << p.latitude << endl;
                }

                inputFile.close();
        }
        else {
                cout <<"Unable to open file";
        }

        return 0;
}
```

Could anyone explain how to work on my above attempt to read in my lat long points from my data file and store it into a vector?

Currently, I get no output from the above.

(I'm not a fluent programmer, as you may have already concluded)

Comment: What's wrong with the code you've written?

Comment: You want to drop other columns of your file, so `std::getline` seems correct.

Comment: @scohe001 I was initially getting the error "unknown escape sequence:  '\040'". I've fixed that now. Now, after a few changes to the script (which I've made to my post), I seem to through compilation, but no output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A *more C++ish* method to do this is to:
1. Overload `operator>>` for your struct.
2. Create a distance method in your struct.
3. Overload operators < and == in your struct.

### Overloading `operator>>`

```
struct Point
{
    double latitude;
    double longitude;
    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& input, Point& p);
};

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& input, Point& p)
{
    input >> p.latitude;
    input >> p.longitude;
    return input;
}
```

Your input could be:

```
std::vector<Point> database;
Point p;
while (data_file >> p)
{
    database.push_back(p);
}
```

**Edit 1: `operator>>` for line reading**

```
std::istream&
operator>>(std::istream& input, Point p)
{
    std::string row_text;
    std::getline(input, row_text);
    std::istringstream row_stream(row_text);
    row_stream >> p.latitude;
    row_stream >> p.longitude;
    return input;
}
```

The usage of `std::getline`, `std::string` and `std::istringstream` can easily be found by searching StackOverflow or the internet.

Comment: At what point on you giving the instruction to take both lay long values of a specific line in the input file so that you can then push_back?

Comment: The expression `(data_file >> p)` reads in the *lay long* values of a specific line.  You can modify `operator>>` to read a line (`std::getline`) into a string, then extract the *lay long* values from the string (`std::istringstream`).

Comment: Could you expand more on how you would modify the operator?

Comment: Looking into `std::getline`, I can see how to obtain, say, the first column by specifying a delimiting character in its constructor, however, I require the first two. I've tried to run the script in the manner you've described. After I `cout << p.latitude << " " << p.longitude << endl;`, I obtain numbers that definitely do not exist in my _.txt_ file.

Comment: Please edit your post with a sample of the input file.  Otherwise I have to guess at what you are trying to achieve.  Have you searched StackOverflow for "c++ read file comma separated struct"?

Comment: I've included a sample of my input